# Script variables not interpreted by sed in cronjob

Tags: bash, shell, sed, debian, bullseye

Bash script in Debian 11 Bullseye making use of "sed" runs ok from command line but not as a cron

Hi, I'm running `Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) Linux 5.15.84-v8+ #1613 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 5 12:03:08 GMT 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

In my setting, I have two bash scripts:

A different script fills in myfolder with JPEG files every minute 24 hours a day, non-stop. It's a cronjob and runs flawlessly.

When run from command line in /home/myuser the script below runs flawlessly and creates a file that lists all JPEG files in myfolder between start time and finish time

eg of filename
`2023-03-05_1014.jpg`

eg of output.txt created from command line
myfolder/2023-03-05_1014.jpg

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/myuser/
current_date=$(date +%F)
time_start=2023-03-05_0900
time_finish=2023-03-05_1700

ls myfolder/"$current_date"_*.jpg | sed -n "/myfolder\/$time_start/, /myfolder\/$time_finish/p" > output.txt
```

When run as a cronjob as user myuser (not root)

`00 22 * * * /home/myuser/create_jpg_list.sh 2>&1`

output.txt will list every single file in myfolder with every JPEG file listed from 0000 through 2359. That is, the variables in the sed command do not seem to be interpreted.

eg of output.txt created from cronjob
`myfolder/2023-03-05_2302.jpg`
this line should not show in output.txt because it is out of the time range 9am to 5pm

I have searched online and there are a few threads such as the links below (to name a few) dealing with this scenario but alas
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614759/sed-doesnt-work-under-cron
https://askubuntu.com/questions/524726/not-able-to-run-sed-on-bash-script
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662851/why-this-script-doesnt-work-from-cron-while-it-works-when-invoke-from-my-shell
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/sed-not-working-from-cron-706865/

Any feedback is welcome as I do not know what else to try.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, your script ignores today's date and hardcodes 2023-03-05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sed address start/finish conditions are "**categorical**".  That is, it is fixed **at first match**.  So, while that works OK for the start condition, capturing the first of many matches, that does not work for the end condition, giving you only the first of many.

Also, there is no "**comparison**" on addresses, so you can't use **1701** as a specification of an end condition.

awk is a better choice for that kind of fine-grained control, while giving greater flexibility on some kinds of matches.

The script below incorporates a **demo mode** (no need to specify command-line parameters) which will demonstrate the output for both, your original **[sed](/questions/tagged/sed)** address matching, and the **[awk](/questions/tagged/awk)** method to give you the result you wanted.

**Logic demonstration script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

demo=0 
sel_date=""

while [ $# -gt -0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --demo )    demo=1 ; shift ;;
        --today )   sel_date=$(date +%F) ; shift ;;
        --date )    sel_date="$2" ; shift ; shift ;;
        --start )   stime="${2}" ; shift ; shift ;;
        --end )     etime="${2}" ; shift ; shift ;;
        --dir )     startdir="${2}" ; shift ; shift ;;
        * ) echo "\n\t Invalid parameter used on command line.  Only valid options: [ --today | --date {yyyy-mm-dd} | --start {hhmm} | --end {hhmm} ]\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ; ;;
    esac
done

if [ ${demo} -eq 1  -o  -z "${startdir}" ]
then
    demo=1
    echo " ****  DEMO MODE IN EFFECT  **** "
    startdir="myuser"
fi
echo "${startdir}"

if [ ${demo} -eq 1  -o  -z "${sel_date}" ]
then
    sel_date="2023-03-05"
fi
echo "${sel_date}"

if [ ${demo} -eq 1  -o  -z "${stime}" ]
then
    stime="0900"
fi
echo "${stime}"

if [ ${demo} -eq 1  -o  -z "${etime}" ]
then
    etime="1700"
fi
echo "${etime}"


if [ ${demo} -eq 1 ]
then

    if [ ! -d myuser ]
    then
        mkdir myuser
    fi
    ###
    ###  Create test environment for logic confirmation
    ###
    for mdate in 2023-02-30  2023-03-05  2023-03-08
    do
        echo -e "\t ${mdate} ..."
        for mtime in 0700 0900 1100 1300 1500 1700 1900
        do
                echo "dummy" >"${startdir}/${mdate}_${mtime}.jpg"
            done
        done
    done
fi

cd `dirname "${startdir}" `

time_start="${sel_date}_${stime}"
time_finish="${sel_date}_${etime}"

ls -1 "${startdir}/${sel_date}_"*.jpg
echo ""

### Method 1 - Inappropriate
ls "${startdir}/${sel_date}_"*.jpg | sed -n "/${startdir}\/${time_start}/, /${startdir}\/${time_finish}/p" | tee output1.txt

wc -l output1.txt


### Method 2 - 
ls "${startdir}/${sel_date}_"*.jpg | 
awk -v pdate="${sel_date}" -v stime="${stime}" -v etime="${etime}" '{
    ### Input format:  'myuser/2023-03-05_0900_001.jpg'
    n=split( $0, line, "/" ) ;
    split( line[n], dat, "_" ) ;
    if( dat[1] == pdate ){
        if( dat[2] >= stime && dat[2] <= etime ){
            print $0 ;
        } ;
    } ;
}' | tee output2.txt
wc -l output2.txt
```

Comment: Your solution WORKS! Great coding skills! Thank you SO much! It took a bit to reply - needed to read your code, understand it, run it, apply it to my script. I'm strugging with _001 in ### Input format:  'myuser/2023-03-05_0900_001.jpg' as current input format myuser/2023-03-05_0900.jpg works perfectly well. Ticked "This answer is useful".

Comment: The script tried to anticipate the variability of the usage context.  The *_001.jpg format was to allow me to create a bunch of files, to demonstrate the parsing, but that does not impact the logic applicable to you case.  Such a change is just a tweak, not defective logic.  I would appreciate it if you recognized that and clicked on the checkmark.

Comment: I've removed the looping on ${count} for the multiple demo files created for any given date.  The logic now matches **exactly** the more focused context which you originally outlined.

Comment: Eric, I do appreciate your feedback and explanations, that's a lot more than expected. This is much appreciated. Super! I clicked on +1 but a pop-up says "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @Mike, thanks for getting back to me.  If the answer resolves the specific "hardpoints" of the original question, then the expectation is that you click on the checkmark just below the up/down arrows.  If it does not resolve those hardpoints, we would appreciate a clarification of where it fails and how, so that those particular points can be adressed and the answer updated.

Comment: Oh yes! I had missed it! Green tick just checked! :)